# Back up sdcard to cloud

Tags: backup, internal-storage, cloud

Problem: I have an internal flash drive (`/sdcard`) with "stuff I don't like losing". Due to a bug in ClockworkMod Recovery, it got wiped the other day. I had been manually backing up my entire card to my local computer every so often, but it was a manual process.

I have a Box.com account. I have a Dropbox account. I have a Google Drive account. I want to automate uploading everything to one of those services (preferably Box, as I got in on the 50GB promo they did). I'm assuming this exists as a free or one-time purchase app, but all I can find are "back up services" that require a subscription.  I use Titanium Backup to back up my apps, I take full images of my phone via CWM every so often, but I can't pass all that data to the cloud (well, TiBu will upload to Box/Dropbox, but that's not everything).

Dropbox has a built-in image backup that will automatically upload any pictures I take to my account. Google+ can do the same to my G+ account. However, that's still only a portion of what exists on my internal storage.  I want something that will grab everything else. Ideas?

Comment: BTW, if this is a dupe, could someone pretty please point me at an answer? I searched, but all I found were phone data (app) backups and image backups.

Comment: Well there're questions dealing with cloud sync, but most of those are specifically about Dropbox.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your device is rooted, you might want to take a look at [Titanium Backup](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.keramidas.TitaniumBackup), which has built-in support for Dropbox, Box and Google drive.

As for your "special folder", I'd say you will probably like [FTPSyncX](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.syncoorp.FTPSyncX_Pro) -- which allows you automatically sync with Dropbox as well as with your local PC via SSH, FTP, and others. The latter can happen automatically all xx Minutes when your Wifi is in reach, or when any Wifi is in reach, or generally... And the App is well supported. Alternatively, there is [FolderSync](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=dk.tacit.android.foldersync.full), additionally offering support for SkyDrive, SugarSync, Ubuntu One, Box.net, LiveDrive, Google Drive, Google Docs, HiDrive, NetDocuments, Amazon S3 and WebDAV.

**FTPSyncX:**

[image: FTPSyncX sync settings] [image: FTPSyncX LogView]

**FolderSync:**

[image: FolderSync choose account] [image: FolderSync Stats]

Comment: Ha! Busted! You didn't read the question did you? ***"I use Titanium Backup to back up my apps"*** :)

Comment: Ouch -- right, missed that part. But that was not the main part of my answer, but rather a "you might also like..." -- as the focus was on syncing the OPs "special folder on internal SD" -- which I don't think is a task TB does care for. So far, you won't bust me as being OT, will you? ;)

Comment: Of course I won't. There's even a smiley at the end of my comment. I just find it funny when someone post something as an answer that was in the question :) Happened to me too.

Comment: I've installed the trial version of FTPsyncX and the lite version of FolderSync, so we'll see how those go. Both look interesting. Thanks for the suggestions!

Comment: @NDGeek You're welcome! I'm using FTPSyncX for quite a while now. Though the design is not that nice-looking as FolderSync's, it works fine for me.

Comment: @Izzy I ended up ruling FTPSyncX out because it doesn't support Box. FolderSync seems to be working pretty well though. I also discovered that the TiBu people make an app that does this, but again, it only  sends to Dropbox at the moment...so FolderSync it is!

Comment: Right, Joel has [Titanium Media Sync](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.keramidas.MediaSync) in the wild. I skipped that in my post as I thought it not close enough to your needs -- and as I can see I was right ;) Glad you found your solution in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to use [SanDisk Memory Zone](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sandisk.mz&hl=en) available from Google Play Store.

Once you have installed the app, run it and it will scan your entire SD card and the internal memory of your device.

After that, choose a cloud storage provider where you would want to backup all the data.

[image: SanDisk Memory Zone Screen Shot]

Comment: This is close, but I'd prefer something that works on a  file/folder level. It also doesn't agree with my system on which storage is internal and which is external. Thanks, though!

Answer (score 0):

I know this comes a little late, but for the sake of others like myself who stumbled upon this question (in my case, it matches word for word my needs, it's spooky) I found something that suits me well.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.kowalczuk.rsync4android

It's rsync over SSH and works very well - provided you're already familiar with both.

Comment: Link is broken.